# Optional context parameter in using statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, using, optional-parameters

I have this method

```
public static List<_Account> Get(_User user, string name = null, SearchType sName = SearchType.Equals)
{
  using (Context context = new Context())
  {
    IQueryable<_Account> query = context.Accounts;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && sName == SearchType.Equals)
      query = query.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(name));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && sName == SearchType.StartsWith)
      query = query.Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith(name));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && sName == SearchType.Contains)
      query = query.Where(r => r.Name.Contains(name));
    return query.ToList();
  }
}
```

This works but when i calling this method from another Method where I already defined a context I want to reuse that context. I would add an optional parameter

```
public static List<_Account> Get(..., Context ctx = null) {...
```

If `ctx != null` I want that context to be used **and not disposed at the end**. Else I want the context created in the using being used and disposed at the end of the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put null into a using block, so the following works:

```
public static List<_Account> Get(_User user, Context contextProvided = null, string name = null, SearchType sName = SearchType.Equals)
{
  using (Context contextInner = (contextProvided == null ? new Context() : null)) //magic here
  {
    Context context = contextProvided ?? contextInner; //magic here

    IQueryable<_Account> query = context.Accounts;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && sName == SearchType.Equals)
      query = query.Where(r => r.Name.Equals(name));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && sName == SearchType.StartsWith)
      query = query.Where(r => r.Name.StartsWith(name));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) && sName == SearchType.Contains)
      query = query.Where(r => r.Name.Contains(name));
    return query.ToList();
  }
}
```

Another good way to do it would be extract the flesh of the method (the query) into a helper method. Then, you can duplicate the now outer method into two overloads. One overload creates a context, one of them takes it as an argument.

If this pattern happens a lot you could achieve something like this by creating a custom `IDisposable` derived class:

```
public static List<_Account> Get(_User user, Context contextProvided = null, ...)
{
  using (var contextProvider = new ContextProvider(contextProvided))
  {
    Context context = contextProvider.EffectiveContext;
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: Of course, I tried the following
`using (Context context = contextProvided ?? new Context()){`
But then I just disposed contextProvided I thought...
Thanks for your answer, this should work

Comment: @fix I fixed it to contextProvided.

Comment: This should be in all books about C# and SQL, have not found anything as useful, very nice pattern with ContextProvider!

Answer (score 0):

Another pattern to use either an internal or external context is:

```
void SomeMethod(Context context = null)
{
    Context contextToDispose = null;
    if(context == null) context = contextToDispose = new ContextCreator();
    
    using(contextToDispose)
    {
        context.DoThings();
    }
}
```